# Not able to install rJava in R

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, java, r

I am not able to install the rJava package in R.

If I run `sudo R CMD javareconf`:

```
*** JAVA_HOME is not a valid path, ignoring
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.8.0_161
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar
trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include - 
I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/linux
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8- 
oracle/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8- 
oracle/jre/../include/linux     
-fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat - 
Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c conftest.c -o 
conftest.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o 
conftest.so conftest.o -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8- 
oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR

JAVA_HOME        : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include - 
I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/linux
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /usr/lib/R
Done.
```

I have also ran the following commands:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

but I don't really know what it is supposed to do...

Finally, it has to be mentioned that

- if I install and run *rJava* (using library(rJava)) in sudo mode everything is ok.
- if I run rJava in normal user mode with

  ```
  library(rJava)
  ```

  I get the following error:

  ```
  library(rJava)
  Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
  .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/home/marc/R/x86_64-pc-linux- 
  gnu-library/3.4/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  ```
- If I try to install rJava in normal user mode I get the same error as the previous when testing if package can be loaded:

  ```
  ** testing if installed package can be loaded
  Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
  .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/home/marc/R/x86_64-pc-linux- 
  gnu-library/3.4/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  Error: loading failed
  Execution halted
  ```

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: I am not sure whether `JAVA_HOME is not a valid path, ignoring` is important here but have you checked that `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` you are setting as `JAVA_HOME` is a valid path in your system and contains a Java installation? If you are following an online guide, please provide a link in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> update-alternatives --config java

This gave an output like this:

- 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java

Add to your /etc/environment

JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle'

And then remove and reinstall r-base:

> sudo apt-get remove r-base
>
> sudo apt-get install r-base

Now try install rJava again.